# Query entity from nodes in NebulaGraph

Tags: nebula-graph

I’m trying to query a NebulaGraph.

I created different nodes with, each of which having their own properties. I know I can query for a specific node, but I want to query for only a specific entity inside a selected node.

For example, I have a "People" node that store name, relation, interaction...
I want to query *People.Name*.

But I can't find how.

I tried to create a new Tag index using

```
CREATE TAG INDEX people_name_index ON People(Name);
```

But it returns *Invalid param*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because inauthentic usage.

Comment: Can you at least explain why? i'am new to nebulagraph.

Comment: Some background information is in *[Is moderator intervention required for these NebulaGraph questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426494/is-moderator-intervention-required-for-these-nebula-graph-questions)*

Comment: (Use `@username`, e.g., @EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine, for notifications.)